# Upgrading websphere from v6 to 7 - what is the best approach

Tags: websphere, upgrade

Hi 
we are upgrading websphere application server(WAS) from v6.x to 7.x
currently WAS is installed at:
`/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer` - default location.
What is the best way to upgrade to 7.x, and recreate profiles with least downtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking just about WAS with no extra IBM products (like Portal, Quickr, Connections, etc) on top of it your best off setting up a new fresh one next to your old one and manually making the configurations (data sources etc). It takes only couple hours to install and update one and if your applications have decent documentation about their requirements it shouldn't take more than a few hours to set up the rest... Then you can simply test it and redirect the traffic.